# Subsection numbering lost

Tags: sectioning, numbering, memoir

I'm using the memoir class and I have put the following lines of code in the preamble:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

So far, everything's worked just fine. But for unknown reasons, LaTeX has suddenly stopped numbering subsections in both the table of contents and the text. Has anyone had the same or a similar problem before and might be able to help me out?

Comment: Full minimal example please. There are other `memoir` macros that can alter this, for example `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{memoir} ... formatting paper, setting headers, rules, etc., color package, ... \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} ... paragraph options, line spacing, citations, ... \begin{document} ... \end{document}

Comment: You should be able to edit your own question, so you can put the MWE inside the question, rather than putting it in a comment where fewer people will see it. Also, you may want to take a look at the link describing what an MWE is and how to go about producing one. Is the MWE that you suggested in the comments one that will actually reproduce the problem? Also, welcome to TeX.SX! `:-)`